# Texturing 2D vectorial terrain (or simply masking texture)

Tags: xna, farseer-physics-engine

I have a procedurally generated terrain, as follows:

[image]

It is generated and then built using Farseer Physics, however I haven't found a way to create and apply a mask to texture it properly, I have already played with stencil buffers and pixel shaders but I still have no solution at the moment. How would I do that? Am I going the right direction with stencil and pixel shader? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to just create some geometry you can actually texture. Just create a quad (2 triangles) for every segment of your world. This should be straight-forward to texture. To optimize this, you can remove quads that leave the screen during gameplay.

For an idea how you could apply your texture using UV coordinates, see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43658/dynamic-terrain-texture/43669#43669).

[image: world geometry]

Comment: I'll accept it as the answer for being the most complete one, even though I successfully implemented my pixel shader approach

Answer (score 0):

taking a different approach i would look to do something similar to http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Random_terrain.php

essentially find what is below the line and generate a color

Comment: That was almost the exact approach I was trying with pixel shader, Thank you for the link